# VB Combobox Index Change on datagridview mouse click row select

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to set my textbox fields to the row column values when the row in the datagridview is double clicked. I have figured out how to populate my textbox fields, however, one of my fields in a combobox, and I can't seem to select the dropdown value according to selected row's column value. This is what I have currently.

```
Private Sub dgvCustomers_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles dgvCustomers.MouseDoubleClick

    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0)

    tbMasterContactID.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
    tbCompany.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString
    tbContact.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString
    tbAddress1.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString
    tbAddress2.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString
    tbCity.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value.ToString
    tbState.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value.ToString
    tbCountry.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(7).Value.ToString
    tbZip.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(8).Value.ToString
    tbZip4.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(9).Value.ToString
    tbEmail.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(10).Value.ToString
    tbPhone.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(11).Value.ToString

    tbStatus.SelectedIndex = tbStatus.FindString(dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(12).Value.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: `tbStatus.SelectedIndex = tbStatus.FindString(dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(12).Value.ToString)
` change it to `tbStatus.Text = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0).Cells(12).Value.ToString
`

Comment: Still not working for me.

Comment: The I would look to make sure there is something in the 12th cell. I am doing this all the time and I know it works. I don't use cell indexes I use the name of the cell, though